# Filename with string cannot be created in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Here, the name of the file, I want, is b0:d5:cc:fc:90:98_Reader_Configuration. 
"b0:d5:cc:fc:90:98" is a string.

After creating the file, the filename I get is  _Reader_Configuration.

```
$newMAC = "b0:d5:cc:fc:90:98"
$newData | Out-File C:\Users\sams\Desktop\Reader_Test\Config_Files\${$newMAC}_Reader_Configuration.json
```

I get the file with the data but not the filename I want. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colons `:` are not allowed in your filename.

See Microsoft docs: [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#naming-conventions)